# SSO Implementaion/Suggestions Needed

Tags: sso

We have a partner who has integrated our services into their application. All API method call's from partner app to our services using standard API key/pwd credentials.

But to make any changes on the file created by API call users has to login again with their own credentials to our web interface.

1. Login to Partner APP to do API Calls
2. Login to Our Web Interface to modify files created at step 1

So the problem we have here, our customer who uses the integration doesn't want to login multiple times...

When user redirected from partner app to our app they just passing file id..

and Partner doesn't want to act as IdP..

I am looking for some suggestion how to handle this situation...

Comment: Have you checked OpenID?

Comment: I am not sure how this option will help. Any notes?

Comment: Basically, OpenID is designed to solve the issue you're trying to solve (at least as far as I understand): that's why I'm asking if you checked it out and, if you did, why it doesn't match your requirement

Comment: can you please help me to understand how OPENID will help solve my issue.